# Colour multiple lines in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm sure this question has been asked before, but I can't find the right answer.

I want to change the colour of my ggplot (contains 4 lines --> of 4 groups), but I cannot change it anyway.

This is what my data looks like:

| Group | Reading | time_min | InverseRedValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 5.700094e-09 |
| 1 | 2 | 60 | 5.523723e-09 |
| 1 | 3 | 120 | 5.626847e-09 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 5.763723e-09 |
| ... | ... | .... | .... |

```
dput(means)
structure(list(Group = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4), 
    Reading = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), time_min = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 60, 60, 60, 60, 120, 120, 120, 120), InverseRedValue = c(5.70009358411786e-09, 
    5.52372329640222e-09, 5.67606031389948e-09, 5.52620331331206e-09, 
    5.7720609617267e-09, 5.65083929197724e-09, 5.66693425707513e-09, 
    5.53771094635231e-09, 5.81966045566988e-09, 5.71366935124808e-09, 
    5.68183272240732e-09, 5.53207966584862e-09), Indi = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -12L
), class = "data.frame")
```

This is how I coded the plot:

```
P <- ggplot(data = means) + 
  geom_line(
    aes(x= time_min, y = InverseRedValue, group = Group, color = (Group))) + 
  xlab("time in minutes") +
  ylab("Inverse Red Value")
```

I tried to change the color by `color = (Group)` into `color = c("color1",...)`

and as well I tried

`+ scale_color_manual(values=c("indianred3","royalblue1","indianred3","royalblue1"))`

but nothing works out...

Comment: Please make your question reproducible by including your data as an object in the question. Paste the data frame into the question with `dput(means)`. This makes it easier for others to test and verify solutions. [MRE] provides guidance.

Comment: Hello Peter, thank you. I added the data frame.

Comment: Are you sure? I cannot see the data.

Comment: The table contains the data

Comment: Sorry but it is not easy to copy the data from the table, it is better to paste the data into the question as an object or more simply using `dput(means)`. I suspect that the data table in the question is a subset of your complete data. If your full data set is large you can paste a subset of the data using `dput(head(means, 20))` but it is important that the data is representative in order to demonstrate the problem and have adequate data to ensure that the solution is applicable to your case.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you! I added it via dput(means)

Comment: Thank you that's much better.

Comment: @Peter agree that ``dput()`` is the best way, but you can use ``clipr::read_clip_tbl()`` to easily access data in table form (after copying it).

Comment: @user438383 thanks for the tip which is new to me, I also sometimes use `overflow::soread()` but it does not always work. The main issue in this case is that the table did not include enough data for me to test the problem;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was this what you were looking for?

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = means) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = time_min, y = InverseRedValue, group = Group, colour = factor(Group))) + 
  scale_color_manual(breaks = 1:4,
                     values = c("indianred3","royalblue1","indianred3","royalblue1"))+
    labs(x = "time in minutes",
       y = "Inverse Red Value",
       colour = "Group")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I got this, too. But I wanted to chance the colours manual, so that they fit to my other graphes.

Comment: Sorry I missed the line in your question with the colours. Have amended the answer to include your preferred colours. One way to do this is to 'map' to the `breaks` vector in the call to `scales_colour_manual()`.

Comment: Thank you, Peter!!! Now it works! I'm not sure what i did wrong the whole time :D

Comment: If this answers your question please consider accepting the answer

Comment: I did. Thanks :)